# How to add custom variable in url without redirect?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I'm trying to add a local variable to my URL.

As an example I have this URL:

```
mysite.com/my-page-name/
```

And I want to add 'en' variable into it and leave the page working properly:

```
mysite.com/en/my-page-name/
```

I tried to deal with it using `add_rewrite_tag()` and `add_rewrite_rule()` but it isn't working so what am I doing wrong?

```
add_rewrite_tag('%locale%', '^([a-z]{2})');
add_rewrite_rule('^([a-z]{2})/(.+)[/$]', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Comment: Why you want to /en/. Are you trying to create your website in Multi-language.

Comment: Hi Aftab. No, I need to have this variable in $wp->query_vars to build pages programaticaly. Some parts I need to show, some parts I need to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a mistake in regexp in rewrite rule. This one works perfectly!

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([a-z]{2})\/(.+)(\/)?$', 'index.php?page=&pagename=$matches[2]&locale=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve it. The most simplest one could be to make a new page and with name "en" so the slug will be `mysite.com/en/`

Now make the "en" page as parent of my-page-name or in other words make my-page-name as a child of en. So slug will be `mysite.com/en/my-page-name/`

Comment: thats a good one :)

Comment: It's not good in my case. Because I have 31 locales and several pages with it. It's too much pages... I need to have this variable in $wp->query_vars to build pages programaticaly. Some parts I need to show, some parts I need to hide.